# how to perform explicit relative import in python2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-import

My team mate added a explicit relative import to the code base.

```
from .modulename import classname
```

Now if I try to run that file, I get the "Attempted relative import in non-package"  error?

I am trying to run this in Python2, he put in this change to make this file compatible with Python3. For the time being, I have to run this file in Python2

The file that I am trying to run and the file that it is trying to import is in the same directory which is the directory from where I am trying to launch this file.

Comment: Explicit relative imports work exactly the same in Python 2 and Python 3. You're probably running your program wrong, and only noticing it now. (The old implicit relative import behavior could hide some of these problems, letting them pile up into bigger problems.)

Comment: Chances are that won't be the only python 3 thing in that file. Why can't you use python 3?

Comment: (Well, either you're running it wrong, or your teammate is. It's hard to be sure which from just this, although it looks more likely that you're running it wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

Explicit relative imports work exactly the same in Python 2 and Python 3. The problem is that one of you is running your code wrong - probably you, although there isn't enough information here to be certain.

If this file is supposed to be part of a package, then you're the one running it wrong. You should *not* be running it directly by filename, and you should not be inside the package directory when you run it. In fact, there's a good chance you shouldn't be running it at all, only importing it from other files. If you do want to run it, the command would be `python -m packagename.modulename` from somewhere where the top-level package is importable - probably the directory containing the package's directory, if the package isn't installed.

If this file is not supposed to be part of a package, then your teammate is running it wrong. The explicit relative import should be converted to an absolute import, and you should add

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

to the top of the file to ensure you don't get any accidental implicit relative imports. In this case, your partner will need to stop running the file however they've been running it.

Comment: My teammate is on leave, so I cannot say definitively who is wrong here. But running it as python -m modulename does sort of solve my problem.  I just need to figure out how to use PDB now. Cause I run my debugger as follows: python -m pdb filename.